# Ubuntu login screen freezing not allowing me to login(mouse works)

Tags: gnome, login, mouse

I tried everything from running recovery mode to drop down in the root shell to uninstall the lxdm and it temporarily worked until the gdm started freezing now. It was a temporary fix. I updated my ubuntu laptop and nothing fixed it. How do I go about this to figure out what the heck is going on? I don't know how to bring up info on the  problem to share with you. I checked ubuntufourums and couldn't find anything to fix my problem. Note: I can login into my accounts before; but I already fixed that problem; but the only problem now is that the mouse  works but the login screen just freezes up where I can't interact with it. I even tried ctrl + alt f1, f2 and etc and it still freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Press Alt+SysRq+R. This will detach the keyboard from the frozen X server. Then you can use Alt+F1 to switch to the console and conduct your research -- look at /var/log/Xorg.0.log, /var/log/ker.log, etc. for possible causes.

Comment: what does altgr mean? does it mean just alt

Comment: Most keyboards I've seen mark the right Alt key as AltGr. Apparently some just have two Alt keys.

Comment: I've just tested and the Left Alt key also works for that purpose, so yes: just Alt.